# Как правильно отобразить один json объект в представлении?

Tags: angular

Я могу отобразить запрашиваемый объект через {{ item | async | json }}
Как получить его вывести в представление нужные мне значения?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ihtp8h?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отобразить данные объекта можно использовать новый компонент.

Передаем в компонент item-view наши данные с async.

```
<div>
  <h3>Вот json объект</h3>
  <pre>
      {{ item | async | json }}
  </pre>
</div>

<hr />

<item-view [item]="item | async"></item-view>
```

В самом компоненте просто отображаем данные и принимаем их через @Input()

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item-view',
  template: `
              <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
              <div>{{ item.name }}</div>`,
})
export class ItemViewComponent {
  @Input() item: any;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам!